# Processing, replacing text

Tags: java, text, processing

I currently got this code for a poster I'm trying to make for a study (Gonna put it all, as it might be relevant):

```
package interactiveposter;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;


public class InteractivePoster extends PApplet {
// Declare variables:

    PImage[] imgs = new PImage[12]; 
    int i = 0;
    boolean introduction = true;
    boolean storyboardtext = true;
    boolean features = true;
    int picWidth = 300;
    int picHeight = 200;
    PImage storyboard;
    PImage phone;

// Set size of window and load images:

    public void setup() {
        size(750,900);
        smooth();
        storyboard = loadImage("C:/Users/Frederik/Desktop/Medialogy AAU/Images/storyboardfixed.png");
        storyboard.resize(270, 757);
        phone = loadImage("C:/Users/Frederik/Desktop/Medialogy AAU/Images/phone.PNG");
        phone.resize(300, 500);
    }

// All that should run continuously goes in draw:

    public void draw() {
        background(255,255,255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(24);
        fill(0);
        text("Creative Play - Applied Technology",width/2,50); 
        textSize(16);
        fill(120);
        text("B-341",width/2,900);
        image(storyboard, 50, 100);
        image(phone, 385, 140);

        int tboxPos = 50;
        tboxPos=tboxPos+335;
        if(introduction == false) {
            features = true;
            text("Text 1...Introduction", 490, 230);
        }

        if(storyboardtext == false) {
            text("Text 2...Storyboard", 480, 230);
        }
        if(features == false) {
            text("Text 3...Features", 480, 230);
            introduction = true;
        }



        fill(0,0,0);
        rect(tboxPos,700, 300, 100, 7); //FrameRect

        fill(102,204,255);
        rect(tboxPos, 700, 300, 50, 7); //IntroductionRect
        fill(255,255,255);
        textSize(20);
        text("Introduction", tboxPos+150, 730);

        fill(102,204,255);
        rect(tboxPos, 750, 150, 50, 7); // StoryboardRect
        fill(255,255,255);
        textSize(20);
        text("Storyboard", tboxPos+75, 780);

        fill(102,204,255);
        rect(tboxPos+150, 750, 150, 50, 7); //FeaturesRect
        fill(255,255,255);
        textSize(20);
        text("Features", tboxPos+225, 780);
    }

// Check if mouse is clicked on one of the images, then change that variable from true to false or opposite

    public void mouseClicked() {
        if(mouseX > 385 && mouseX < 685 && mouseY > 700 && mouseY < 750)
        {
            if(introduction == true) introduction = false;
            else introduction = true;
        }
        if(mouseX > 385 && mouseX < 535 && mouseY > 750 && mouseY < 800)
        {
            if(storyboardtext == true) storyboardtext = false;
            else storyboardtext = true;
        }
        if(mouseX > 535 && mouseX < 685 && mouseY > 750 && mouseY < 800)
        {
            if(features == true) features = false;
            else features = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Poster: [image]

So when you push the buttons below the smartphone, relevant text should appear. For now it works individually, I click introduction, but to see one of the others I have to click introduction again to make it dissapear first. 
What I need to do is make the text replace the other when another button is clicked.

I tried putting the other texts to true in the if statements, but it only worked for some of them, the others got kind of blocked.

Another thought was doing something in void mouseClicked(), but I'm unsure what.

Help is highly appreciated, thank you =)

Comment: So for storyboard click-handler, you should simply do `storyboard = true; introduction = false; features = false;` You don't need if-statements etc.

Comment: I think what you mean is what i mentioned as what I tried, could you try showing how you did, I might have misplaced the code

Comment: I updated my comment. Just do `prop1 = true; prop2 = false; prop3 = false;` for `prop1` and similarly for each other property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're only setting one variable for each button. Instead, what you want to do is set **all** of the variables.

Here is one example:

```
if(mouseX > 385 && mouseX < 685 && mouseY > 700 && mouseY < 750){
   if(introduction == true){
      introduction = false;
   }
   else{
      features = false
      storyboardtext = false;
      introduction = true;
   }
}
```

By the way, you could shorten all of the above:

```
if(mouseX > 385 && mouseX < 685 && mouseY > 700 && mouseY < 750){
   features = false
   storyboardtext = false;
   introduction = !introduction;
}
```

You might also consider using an `enum` instead of 3 separate `boolean` values.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an integer to keep track of states, with more states boolean become harder to manage and it's easier to make mistakes.

Here's a basic example:

```
final int INTRODUCTION = 0;
final int STORYBOARD = 1;
final int FEATURES = 2;
int state = INTRODUCTION;

void draw(){
  switch(state){
    case INTRODUCTION:
      drawIntroduction();
    break;
    case STORYBOARD:
      drawStoryboard();
    break;
    case FEATURES:
      drawFeatures();
    break;
  }
}

void drawIntroduction(){
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  text("Introduction",15,15);
}
void drawStoryboard(){
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  text("Storyboard",15,55);
}
void drawFeatures(){
  background(192);
  fill(64);
  text("Features",15,95);
}

void keyReleased(){
  state = (state + 1) % 3;//cycle through states to test
}
```

I recommend using separate functions for drawing each state to keep the code tidier. Press any key to cycle through states.

The above, roughly adapted to your code, would look a bit like this:

```
package interactiveposter;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;


public class InteractivePoster extends PApplet {
// Declare variables:

    PImage[] imgs = new PImage[12]; 
    int i = 0;
    int picWidth = 300;
    int picHeight = 200;
    PImage storyboard;
    PImage phone;

    final int INTRODUCTION = 0;
    final int STORYBOARD = 1;
    final int FEATURES = 2;
    int state = INTRODUCTION;


// Set size of window and load images:

    public void setup() {
        size(750,900);
        smooth();
        storyboard = loadImage("C:/Users/Frederik/Desktop/Medialogy AAU/Images/storyboardfixed.png");
        storyboard.resize(270, 757);
        phone = loadImage("C:/Users/Frederik/Desktop/Medialogy AAU/Images/phone.PNG");
        phone.resize(300, 500);
    }

// All that should run continuously goes in draw:

    public void draw() {
        background(255,255,255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(24);
        fill(0);
        text("Creative Play - Applied Technology",width/2,50); 
        textSize(16);
        fill(120);
        text("B-341",width/2,900);
        image(storyboard, 50, 100);
        image(phone, 385, 140);

        int tboxPos = 50;
        tboxPos=tboxPos+335;
        if(state == INTRODUCTION) {
            text("Text 1...Introduction", 490, 230);
        }

        if(state == STORYBOARD) {
            text("Text 2...Storyboard", 480, 230);
        }
        if(state == FEATURES) {
            text("Text 3...Features", 480, 230);
        }



        fill(0,0,0);
        rect(tboxPos,700, 300, 100, 7); //FrameRect

        fill(102,204,255);
        rect(tboxPos, 700, 300, 50, 7); //IntroductionRect
        fill(255,255,255);
        textSize(20);
        text("Introduction", tboxPos+150, 730);

        fill(102,204,255);
        rect(tboxPos, 750, 150, 50, 7); // StoryboardRect
        fill(255,255,255);
        textSize(20);
        text("Storyboard", tboxPos+75, 780);

        fill(102,204,255);
        rect(tboxPos+150, 750, 150, 50, 7); //FeaturesRect
        fill(255,255,255);
        textSize(20);
        text("Features", tboxPos+225, 780);
    }

// Check if mouse is clicked on one of the images, then change that variable from true to false or opposite

    public void mouseClicked() {
        if(mouseX > 385 && mouseX < 685 && mouseY > 700 && mouseY < 750)
        {
          state = INTRODUCTION;
        }
        if(mouseX > 385 && mouseX < 535 && mouseY > 750 && mouseY < 800)
        {
            state = STORYBOARD;
        }
        if(mouseX > 535 && mouseX < 685 && mouseY > 750 && mouseY < 800)
        {
            state = FEATURES;
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I'm unable to test this code(so there may be syntax errors), but the concept explained should be clear.

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303824/assign-states-various-values-in-processing/32306042#32306042) on a similar question and also the **Button** sample (under **File > Examples > Topics > GUI > Button** in Processing)